# Counter inside a for loop does not give expected output

Tags: c, for-loop, variable-assignment

This program scans for some characters, and shows how many `'x'`'s were given as input.
I think you'll get a better idea looking at the code instead of me explaining.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n,i,t=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char ara[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &ara[i]);
        if(ara[i]=='x') t++;
    }
    printf("%d",t);
}
```

suppose, `n` = `5` and the characters were `"xxxxxx"`. In that case, the value of `t` should be `5`. But it displays `4`.

Another thing is that if you remove the first scanf Statement (line 5) and manually set the value of `n` = `5` everywhere else in the Code:

```
int n,i,t=0;
//scanf("%d",&n);
n = 5;
```

then the value of `t` becomes `5` resulting in the correct output. Is there any possibility that the outer scanf function is affecting the scanf function inside for loop?

Comment: Your output is 100% pure text. Please do not paste huge screenshots to show 4 lines of test. Instead you can easily copy&paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: Okay! I will remember that later on :)

Comment: It's not too late to edit your question. :) Just click on "edit" below your question and replace the images of text with the text itself.

Comment: Please note that you should use one of the proper signatures of `main`, like `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ara array contains the newline right after you entered `5`. To discard this newline (and all newlines and spaces before the first 'x') you should put space after `%d`:

```
scanf("%d ",&n);
```

**Edit**

You could prepend a space before "%c" like in the answer by @Blaze, but then input like the following will be misread:

```
 5
 x x x x x
```

It will be read as `'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'` instead of `'x', ' ', 'x', ' ', 'x'`.

**Addendum**:

If you want to discard just one newline, and not all newlines:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
while (true) {
    char ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n') break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you enter your `n`, you're also entering a newline (or a space). This whitespace is left in the buffer, so the first character read in won't be the `x`, but that whitespace character.

You can fix that by telling `scanf` to skip the leading whitespace. Change this line

scanf("%c", &ara[i]);

To this:

scanf(" %c", &ara[i]);

The space in front of the `%c` makes it ignore that newline/space and instead take the first `x` entered, giving you the correct result. This is how a [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) explains it:

> Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace
>   characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character
>   (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters --
>   see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any
>   quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including
>   none).